# Como setteo un Date en el main

Tags: java

Tengo un atriuto date y quiero settearlo con una fecha dada por teclado pero no se si lo he realizado bien o no.

```
System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha de la reparacion: ");
                try {
                    String fecha1 = entrada.nextLine(); //El usuario ingresa la fecha a parsear
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY"); //Formato de conversión
                    Date fechaConvertida1 = format.parse(fecha1); //Se parsea la fecha
                    p.setFechaReparacion(fechaConvertida1);
                } catch (Exception i) {
                    System.err.println("No se ha podido convertir la fecha");
```

hasta aquí mas o menos bien pero luego tengo una fecha que he de meter por teclado y añadirla a un método y ya me da un error porque no se que meterle

```
System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha del parte: ");
                try {
                    String fecha2 = entrada.nextLine(); //El usuario ingresa la fecha a parsear
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY"); //Formato de conversión
                    Date fechaConvertida2 = format.parse(fecha2); //Se parsea la fecha
                } catch (Exception i) {
                    System.err.println("No se ha podido convertir la fecha");
                }

                e.añadirMateriales(aux, fechaConvertida2, m);
```

como veis el método necesita 3 cosas como parámetros y una de ella es la fecha que he de meter

Comment: SImplemente lo que deseas es que el usuario introduzca por teclado una fecha (`String`) y la parsees a `Date` no?

Comment: Te estás equivocando con el formato, para el año de cuatro dígitos deber usar la `y` en minúscula, de lo contrario te creará fechas erróneas. Prueba así: **`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");`**, entonces te admitirá fechas escritas en el formato: `16-04-2019`. [Revisa la documentación y los ejemplos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), verás que nunca se usa `YYYY` en mayúsculas.

Answer (score -1):

Aqui tienes la solucion. Acuerdate de que el **usuario** debe introducir la fecha  seperada por `/`, es decir, si introduces esto : `10-10-2010` te dara **ERROR** pero si introduces esto `10/10/2010` te lo **parseara correctamente**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *

 */
public class Stack_pregunta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str_fecha = null;
        Date fecha = null;

        //Pido la fecha (String) al usuario
        try {
            System.out.println("Porfavor, introduzca una fecha (dd-MM-YYYY)");
            System.out.print("--> ");
            str_fecha = br.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al leer por teclado la fecha introducida por el usuario. Error = "+e);
        }

        //Intento parsear la fecha a mi objeto Date
        try {
            fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(str_fecha);
        } catch (Exception  e) {
            System.out.println("Error al parsear la fecha con fomato 'dd-MM-YYYY'. Error = "+e);
        }

        //Finalmente tenemos la fecha parseada a Date

        System.out.println("Fecha (Date) => "+fecha);

    }




}
```

Comment: No es correcto lo que dices. Definiendo un formato así: `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");` de pueden introducir fechas escritas así: `16-04-2019`, el problema es que estaba usando la `y` en mayúscula, y eso produciría fechas erróneas. Lo puedes probar si quieres.